# Escaped Backslash + Alphabetic char to be parsed into its Special Character form

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have an output giving me a string that's *supposed* to be a special character but I'm actually getting the raw characters.

Example (let's say it's a "fake" tab character)

```
               \                           t
outputVar === String.fromCharCode(92) + String.fromCharCode(116) -> true
```

but I need it to eventually become  ex (real tab Character)

```
outputVar === String.fromCharCode(9)
```

I WANT something that looks like this, or at least functions this way, since this seems to be the most dynamic and with least code

```
var newGoodOutput =  String.fromCharCode(escapeCharCode) + badOutput.split("")[1]
```

I DONT want to do this although I know it would work

```
var dontWantThis = {
   "\\t": "\t",
   etc
};
```

Comment: Charcode 92 is backslash, not forward slash.

Comment: Where are you getting this string? If it contains literal escape sequences, it may be JSON, and you should use `JSON.decode()` to decode it.

Comment: It's not a JSON - it's a string. - updated the backslash.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's anything better than a table like the one you don't want. Other than the JSON decoder, I don't think there's anything built-in to parse escape sequences.

Comment: Or fix the code that's generating the output so it produces raw strings instead of escape sequences.

Comment: I would fix it but it's coming in through an angular directive attribute attr-here="\t" and it looks like Angular is trying to "help it"